# Why do I get these "Could not find class" messages?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run my app, regardless whether on a device or an emulator, I get a series of (red) `"Could not find class"` messages in my Android Studio logs. The app is running fine, though. What is wrong with my setup? I use gradle 2.1.0.

Here's the log:

```
07-06 17:18:26.154 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
07-06 17:18:26.224 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.myApp.main.SplashActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:26.254 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method info.myApp.main.SplashActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:26.274 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method info.myApp.main.SplashActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:26.315 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.myApp.main.SplashActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:26.315 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method info.myApp.main.SplashActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:26.345 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method info.myApp.main.SplashActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:26.365 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.myApp.main.SplashActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:26.405 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method info.myApp.main.SplashActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:26.415 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method info.myApp.main.SplashActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:27.015 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.myApp.main.MainActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:27.035 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method info.myApp.main.MainActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:27.075 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method info.myApp.main.MainActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:27.125 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.myApp.main.MainActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:27.125 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method info.myApp.main.MainActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:27.185 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method info.myApp.main.MainActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:27.205 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.UserHandle', referenced from method info.myApp.main.MainActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:27.205 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method info.myApp.main.MainActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:27.205 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method info.myApp.main.MainActivity.access$super
07-06 17:18:27.936 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.animation.StateListAnimator', referenced from method info.myApp.view.SquareFrameLayout.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.026 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.view.SquareFrameLayout.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.106 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.view.SquareFrameLayout.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.166 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.view.SquareFrameLayout.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.196 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.view.SquareFrameLayout.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.377 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewOutlineProvider', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.VerticalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.387 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.VerticalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.477 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnContextClickListener', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.VerticalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.527 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnScrollChangeListener', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.VerticalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.567 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.VerticalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.587 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.VerticalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.817 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.animation.StateListAnimator', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.VerticalCirclePageIndicator.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.857 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.VerticalCirclePageIndicator.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.877 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.VerticalCirclePageIndicator.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.887 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.VerticalCirclePageIndicator.access$super
07-06 17:18:28.897 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.VerticalCirclePageIndicator.access$super
07-06 17:18:29.438 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewOutlineProvider', referenced from method info.myApp.view.DrawableView.access$super
07-06 17:18:29.468 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener', referenced from method info.myApp.view.DrawableView.access$super
07-06 17:18:29.528 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnContextClickListener', referenced from method info.myApp.view.DrawableView.access$super
07-06 17:18:29.578 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnScrollChangeListener', referenced from method info.myApp.view.DrawableView.access$super
07-06 17:18:29.608 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.view.DrawableView.access$super
07-06 17:18:29.648 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.view.DrawableView.access$super
07-06 17:18:31.059 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.animation.StateListAnimator', referenced from method info.myApp.view.Zoomable2BBoxMapView.access$super
07-06 17:18:31.149 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.view.Zoomable2BBoxMapView.access$super
07-06 17:18:31.179 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.view.Zoomable2BBoxMapView.access$super
07-06 17:18:31.199 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.view.Zoomable2BBoxMapView.access$super
07-06 17:18:31.219 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.view.Zoomable2BBoxMapView.access$super
07-06 17:18:31.890 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewOutlineProvider', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.HorizontalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:31.910 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.HorizontalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:31.950 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnContextClickListener', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.HorizontalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.120 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnScrollChangeListener', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.HorizontalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.140 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.HorizontalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.270 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.HorizontalPager.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.400 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.animation.StateListAnimator', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.HorizontalCirclePageIndicator.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.440 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.HorizontalCirclePageIndicator.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.440 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.HorizontalCirclePageIndicator.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.450 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.HorizontalCirclePageIndicator.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.450 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.pager.HorizontalCirclePageIndicator.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.631 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewOutlineProvider', referenced from method info.myApp.view.StylableMediaController.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.641 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnApplyWindowInsetsListener', referenced from method info.myApp.view.StylableMediaController.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.691 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnContextClickListener', referenced from method info.myApp.view.StylableMediaController.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.731 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.View$OnScrollChangeListener', referenced from method info.myApp.view.StylableMediaController.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.781 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.ViewStructure', referenced from method info.myApp.view.StylableMediaController.access$super
07-06 17:18:32.811 32218-32218/info.myApp E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method info.myApp.view.StylableMediaController.access$super
07-06 17:18:51.980 32218-32758/info.myApp E/BellagioCore: ST Static Component Loader : Cannot open OpenMAX registry file /tmp/.omxregister

                                                                                     [ 07-06 17:18:51.980 32218:32758 D/         ]
07-06 17:18:55.173 32218-32758/info.myApp E/BellagioCore: ST Static Component Loader : Cannot open OpenMAX registry file /tmp/.omxregister

                                                                                     [ 07-06 17:18:55.173 32218:32758 D/         ]
                                                                                 In STEOMXCodecsPlugin:: GetpOMX_Init passed
```

Comment: Can you clean your project and rebuild?

Comment: I did clean and rebuild about a thousand times ... No change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs that you're getting are normal. They simply represent those classes that are referred from your code ***conditionally***. So, it doesn't matter if they exist or not.

They are not found because they don't exist on your device or the emulator at which you're running the app.

*Why don't they exist?* Because they were introduced in newer Android versions.

Pickup your first class from the log for example:

> Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap'

ArrayMap was introduced in [API level 19](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArrayMap.html), probably you're running your app on an older version.

**Extra Stuff:**

Since the app is running perfectly fine, you can ignore these messages. The only time you will have a problem because of a missing class would be when you try executing a code that depends upon these classes. And in such cases, for example for the ArrayMap, you can use `android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap` instead of the regular `android.util.ArrayMap`

Comment: Yes! I just realized the difference between my developer phone (API level 18) and a "new" emulator (API level 23). What I don't understand is how you use the term "conditionally". Are you saying that the log messages show up only if I try to access those classes from within conditional clauses (like if, switch, ternary)?

Comment: The ArrayMap is being referred to from your code for sure. As the app is not crashing and working with all its features, the call must be conditional, that's the only logical conclusion. Since you're not the one making the conditional call, it must have been handled at the android system level.